# AngularJS - Loop data with dynamic total number

Tags: angularjs

I try to create a input number that provided total number for loop my `span` tag [like](http://jsfiddle.net/gu7K2/)

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="number"> 
    <li ng-repeat="n in [] | range:{{number}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" >{{n}}</span></li>
</div>
```

And here is my JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myCtrl($scope){
}    

app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(val, range) {
    range = parseInt(range);
    for (var i=0; i<range; i++)
      val.push(i);
    return val;
  };
});
```

But that's not working. How to do that thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to interpolate `{{number}}` inside the `ng-repeat` directive, you can directly use it as it is.

change:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="number"> 
    <li ng-repeat="n in [] | range:{{number}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" >{{n}}</span></li>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="number"> 
    <li ng-repeat="n in [] | range:number"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" >{{n}}</span></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the expression `{{number}}` with the model `number` in the `range filter`.
Updated code:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="number"> 
    <li ng-repeat="n in [] | range: number"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" >{{n}}</span></li>
</div>
```